# Re-ordering hash items to have some appear at the end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm returning a hash of form inputs, which at the moment looks like:

```
hash = {
 "body"=>:text,
 "button_text"=>:string,
 "category"=>:integer,
 "dashboard"=>:boolean,
 "feature"=>:integer,
 "featured_from"=>:datetime,
 "featured_to"=>:datetime,
 "global"=>:boolean,
 "hyperlink"=>:string,
 "jobs"=>:boolean,
 "labs"=>:boolean,
 "leaderboard"=>:boolean,
 "management"=>:boolean,
 "news"=>:boolean,
 "objectives"=>:boolean,
 "only_for_enterprise_users"=>:boolean,
 "published_at"=>:datetime,
 "title"=>:string,
 "workflow_state"=>:string
}
```

I need to place the following keys at the end:

```
["dashboard", "jobs", "labs", "management", "news", "objectives", "global"]
```

Which will leave me with:

```
{
 "body"=>:text,
 "button_text"=>:string,
 "category"=>:integer,
 "feature"=>:integer,
 "featured_from"=>:datetime,
 "featured_to"=>:datetime,
 "hyperlink"=>:string,
 "only_for_enterprise_users"=>:boolean,
 "published_at"=>:datetime,
 "title"=>:string,
 "workflow_state"=>:string,
 "dashboard"=>:boolean,
 "jobs"=>:boolean,
 "labs"=>:boolean,
 "leaderboard"=>:boolean,
 "management"=>:boolean,
 "news"=>:boolean,
 "objectives"=>:boolean,
 "global"=>:boolean
}
```

All the links I've found relate to transforming keys / values without re-ordering, and outside of manually deleting each key and then reinserting I can't see another way of getting my desired output.

Is there an easy way to achieve what I need?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to add this values at the end of hash or in between hash?

Comment: This is a fundamentally bad idea. Hashes happen to be implemented to maintain insertion order in ruby, but as a concept, it's an unordered data structure. Some languages even explicitly randomize order every time you try to read from a hashmap. If you need order, use an array.

Comment: The front end is setup to expect a hash with a list of inputs so I don't have much choice here although I appreciate your points about hashes being unordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try following,

```
(hash.keys - end_keys + end_keys).map { |key| [key, hash[key]] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = { "body"=>:text, "button_text"=>:string, "category"=>:integer,
         "dashboard"=>:boolean, "feature"=>:integer }
enders = ["button_text", "dashboard"]

hash.dup.tap { |h| enders.each { |k| h.update(k=>h.delete(k)) } }
```

See [Object#tap](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-tap), [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete).

`dup` may of course be removed if `hash` can be mutated, which may be reasonable as only the keys are being reordered.